# Compare a string with "$" in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a strings like this in the middle of a file that I am parsing.

```
$t
$a
```

My aim is to eliminate such lines. So I want something like this...

```
if($line matches "$") {
next; #Go to next line of the file and do not process further
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `^\$.*$` should do it for you

Comment: is that the `$t` appears only on the start?

Comment: it would be like `if($line =~ m/\$/) {`

Comment: you should escape `$` first as it is the keyword for regex

Comment: @Avinash $t appears at the start after some spaces
Thanks Avinash... It worked...!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this,

```
if($line =~ m/^\h*\$/m) {
next; #Go to next line of the file and do not process further
}
```

`^` asserts that we are at the start and `\h*` matches zero or more horizontal space characters.

Comment: No I did not downvote. I was stating you could write it like this.